# Work with another developer on same xcode project, provisioning profile issue

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm working with another developer on an iOS app. We're using Mercurial as source control. It's my first time with this setup so I'm probably doing something wrong here.

We both have separate provisioning profiles. No teams profile. Xcode 5.0.1.

Every time I commit the file project.pbxproj looks like I'm changing the provisioning profile info also on his machine.

Is there a way to avoid this kind of situation?

Looks like this is a common question, and I've browsed lot of similar issues here on SO. My situation looks like the one depicted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186679/provisioning-profile-stored-in-xcode-project-file-for-ios-apps), but the solution of setting everything to "Automatic" doesn't solve the problem (by the way, I don't have any automatic option in the Provisioning profile field....)

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877518/ignore-certain-lines-when-merging-files

Comment: Can you show what you're selecting when you say you have no automatic option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628530/which-xcode-project-files-can-i-exclude-from-my-git-repo).

It lists a very short files to be ignored or included in the project folder to avoid conflicts on certificates and provisioning profiles.

Comment: but provisioning profile is configured in project.pbxproj which you are not ignoring or excluding, so how does it work?

Comment: hi @DmitryFink did u get an answer for that ? I am stuck with the same .

Answer (score 1):

Ignore these files when commiting the xproj file:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
*.xccheckout
```

Comment: thx @Nikos for your answer. Unfortunately my mercurial client doesn't show me any of these files. Are they part of the project.pbxproj bundle?

Comment: Yes, expand the pdxproj bundle (it actually a folder) and there are inside there.

Comment: Thx, I supposed so.... I need to figure out how to make them visible to my mercurial client. Right now I don't have any option to ignore single contents of the package :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129912/mercurial-and-xcuserdata-ds-store-and-git